# Why is the output missing the first letter when I use strcat() in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, chararray

Here I want to merge two char arrays and put them into the first char array
But when I cout the second one, it is missing the first letter.
why?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    
    char s1[4] = "one";
    char s2[4] = "two" ;
    
    strcat(s1, s2);
    cout << s1 << endl; //onetwo
    
    cout  << s2; // wo

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How long would the concatenated string be (including the null terminator)?  How much space is in `s1`?

Comment: Attempting to place a string with six characters into an array that's only big enough for three (excluding the zero terminator) is not going to work.

Comment: Just as a side note: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/12149471)

Comment: There is a very valid learning opportunity underlying this question. If it's going to be closed, hopefully you can at least point to a duplicate question. Are all cases of undefined behavior closed as "not reproducible"? Separately, the question I want to ask the OP is why they are using C strings instead of C++ strings. If it's homework, I hope their instructor is planning to explain that this coding style is from antiquity and there's no legitimate use of bare `strcat()` in modern C++.

Comment: Why are you using `strcat` in C++ in the first place? And please, please, *stop* learning from whomever taught you to `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`, as fast as possible.

Comment: @BrentBradburn — it wasn’t closed as not reproducible. It was closed as a typo. Some people seem to think that if it would be a typo if they wrote it then it’s a typo if anyone wrote it. You’re absolutely right that it deserves more serious consideration than that.

Answer (score 1):

When calling the function `strcat`, it is required that you pass as the first argument a pointer to a memory buffer that is large enough to store the concatenated string.

In your case, the concatented string has a length of 6 characters (`"onetwo"`), so the memory buffer must have a size of at least 7 characters (including the terminating null character). However, in your case, the memory buffer has a size of only 4 characters, which is insufficient. Therefore, your program is invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which means that anything can happen. This includes the behavior that you describe in the question.

To fix the problem, you must make the array `s1` at least 7 characters long:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    char s1[7] = "one";
    char s2[4] = "two" ;
    
    strcat(s1, s2);

    cout << s1 << endl;    
    cout << s2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This program has the desired output:

```
onetwo
two
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you should use `std::string` for working with strings:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string s1 = "one";
    std::string s2 = "two";

    s1 += s1; // append s2 to s1

    std::cout << s1 << '\n';
    std::cout << s2 << '\n';
}
```

```
oneone
two
```